# How to create custom rule for jQuery Validate for SUM of textbox with addClassRule?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have created textbox field dynamically in html.I want to add jquery validation custome rule for SUM of all textbox must be 100 using AddClass. But its not working. How to create Jquery validation custome rule using addClass for sum of all textbox field.

bellow is screenshot,
[image]

here is my HTMl code,

```
 <div class="kyc-tab-form-wrap">
                            <h2 class="kyc-tab-form-heading">Geographic Information</h2>

                            <div class="geographic-info-wrap">
                                <span class="red text-center">(*) Please mention your business % against below geographies</span>

                                <ul class="geographic-subheading">
                                    <li>Business Description</li>
                                    <li>Business %</li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="geographic-content">

                                    @for (int i = 0; i < (ViewBag.GeoLocation).Count; i = i + 2)
                                    {
                                    <div class="geographic-row">
                                        <div class="w175">
                                            <label>@ViewBag.GeoLocation[i].Text</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="w65">
                                            <input type="text" name="LocationID_@ViewBag.GeoLocation[i].Value" data-value="@ViewBag.GeoLocation[i].Value"  placeholder="0.00%" class="geoBussinessPer">
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="w175">
                                            <label>@ViewBag.GeoLocation[i + 1].Text</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="w65">
                                            <input type="text" name="LocationID_@ViewBag.GeoLocation[i+1].Value" data-value="@ViewBag.GeoLocation[i+1].Value"  placeholder="0.00%" class="geoBussinessPer">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    }
                                    <div class="geographic-row">
                                        <div class="w175">
                                            <label>Total</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="w65">
                                            <input type="text" id="txtGeoBussinessTotal" class="GeoBussinessTotal" name="geoBussinessPerTotal"  readonly="readonly">
                                        </div>
                                        @*<span id="ErrorGeoTotal" style="color: rgb(185, 74, 72); font-size: 12px; display:none">Total must be 100.</span>*@
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

I have created  jquery validation custome rule for AddClass as bellow,

```
  // custom validate method for echking the sum boxes amounts 
$.validator.addClassRules("geoBussinessPer", function (value, element) {

    return !$(element).hasClass('invalid');
}, "Total must be 100");


// set the change event of each input
$('.geoBussinessPer').blur(function () {

    var boxes = $('.geoBussinessPer'),
        total = 0;

    $(boxes).each(function () {
        total += !isNaN(parseInt(this.value)) ? parseInt(this.value) : 0;
    });

    $(".GeoBussinessTotal").val(total);

    // is it more than 100 ? 
    if (total == 100) {
        boxes.addClass('invalid');
    } else {
        boxes.removeClass('invalid');
        boxes.removeClass('error');
    }
});


 $("#kycFormReg").validate({
      rules: {

           geoBussinessPer: {
            required:true,
            number: true
        },
       messages: {
               geoBussinessPer:"Total must be 100",
       }

        }
})
```

Comment: [Did you read the documentation at all?](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addClassRules/)  `.addClassRules()` is for making "compound" rules... it only accepts a list of `key:value` pairs and is used to combine existing rules into a single rule that can be applied to your fields using a class name.  It does not accept a function or error message.

Answer (score 1):

[Please read the documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addClassRules/); it will make life easier.  `.addClassRules()` only accepts a list of `key:value` pairs and is used to combine existing rules into a single "compound" rule that can be applied to your fields using a class name.  It does not accept a function or error message.

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules("className", {
    required: true,
    minlength: 2
});
```

If you want to create your own custom rule using a function, then you would use [the `.addMethod()` method](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/).

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("geoBussinessPer", function(value, element) {
    return !$(element).hasClass('invalid');
}, "Total must be 100");
```

Although it seems very weird to me that this custom rule is doing nothing but looking for a class on a field.  Instead, this function should be evaluating the user's input.

---

You also seem to be a little confused about how to declare the rules using the `rules` object.  You're missing the name of your field, and the `messages` object does NOT go inside of the `rules` object.

```
$("#kycFormReg").validate({
      rules: {
           geoBussinessPer: {
            required:true,
            number: true
        },
       messages: {
               geoBussinessPer:"Total must be 100",
       }

        }
})
```

Should be...

```
$("#kycFormReg").validate({
    rules: {
        myField: {  // <- NAME of your field
            // list all rules for myField here
            geoBussinessPer: true, // <- name of your custom method
            required:true,
            number: true
        }
     },
     messages: {  // <- SIBLING of rules object
         myField: {  // <- NAME of your field
             // custom messages for myField listed here.
             // geoBussinessPer: "Total must be 100" // message not needed since same is already defined elsewhere
         }
    }
});
```